# Trying to retrieve value from database and validate with user input

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to type the same username in my database it shows my toast, but when I tried to input a username that doesn't exist in the database but it's not working.

```
public class CustomerRegister extends AppCompatActivity {


    //    Variables
    EditText usernamefield, emailfield, passwordfield, repasswordfield;
    Button signupbtn;

    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    String username = "";
    String email = "";
    String password = "";
    Customer customer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_register);

        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("Customer");


        usernamefield = findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        emailfield = findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        passwordfield = findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        repasswordfield = findViewById(R.id.repasswordField);
        signupbtn = findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);



        //save to firebase when clicked
        signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener (){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){


//                get all value along with validation
            if (usernamefield.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                usernamefield.setError("is required");
            }
            if (emailfield.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                emailfield.setError("is required");
            }

            if (passwordfield.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                passwordfield.setError("is required");
            }
            if (repasswordfield.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                repasswordfield.setError("is required");
            } else if (!(repasswordfield.getText().toString().equals(passwordfield.getText().toString()))) {
                repasswordfield.setError("password doesnt match");
            }



            if (!passwordfield.getText().toString().equals("") && passwordfield.getText().toString().equals(repasswordfield.getText().toString()) && passwordfield.getText().length() >= 8) {

                password = passwordfield.getText().toString();
                username = usernamefield.getText().toString();
                email = emailfield.getText().toString();

                            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    String usernameFromDB = snapshot.child(username).child("username").getValue(String.class);

                                    usernameNotExist = usernameFromDB;

                                    if (!(usernameFromDB.equals(username))){
                                        Log.d("myapp",username);
                                        //  store value to database
                                        customer = new Customer(username, email, password);
                                        reference.child(username).setValue(customer);


                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashScreen.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d("myapp",username);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                }
                            });




            } else
                passwordfield.setError("must have at least 8 characters and makesure you enter the same password");

            }
        });

        usernamefield.getText().clear();
        emailfield.getText().clear();
        passwordfield.getText().clear();
        repasswordfield.getText().clear();
    }
}
```

it shows me this error after the 2nd time I entered the username.

```
2021-08-08 20:27:38.898 29236-29236/com.example.efutric E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.efutric, PID: 29236
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.efutric.CustomerRegister$1.onDataChange(CustomerRegister.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Can anyone help troubleshoot what's wrong with my code?

this is where i initialize my reference

```
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_register);




        usernamefield = findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        emailfield = findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        passwordfield = findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        repasswordfield = findViewById(R.id.repasswordField);
        signupbtn = findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);


        //save to firebase when clicked
        signupbtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("Customer");
```

this is what inside my database

```
{
  "Customer" : {
    "asdasd" : {
      "email" : "asdasd",
      "password" : "asdasdasd",
      "username" : "asdasd"
    },
    "qwe" : {
      "email" : "qwe",
      "password" : "qweqweqwe",
      "username" : "qwe"
    },
    "zabidman" : {
      "email" : "zabidemail",
      "password" : "12345678",
      "username" : "zabidman"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All we can say from the current info is that `snapshot.child(username).child("username").getValue(String.class)` returns `null`, and calling `toString()` on `null` leads to the error you get. To help better, show us how `reference` is initialized, and what data you have in the database at that path (as text, no screenshots please). ;You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also responded with @.

Comment: i just edited my question and thank you for the respond as this is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow. @AlexMamo

Comment: How is the `reference` object defined?

Comment: FirebaseDatabse rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Customer"); @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried to get `rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("Customer");` out of the `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: let me try it @AlexMamo

Comment: still not working. i got the same error. @AlexMamo

Comment: Does `usernamefield.getText().toString()` return `asdasd` if you type in your EditText?

Comment: yes it did returned @AlexMamo

Comment: but it didnt return if i type different name in editext @AlexMamo. i already tried using Log.d() to see if its return or not

Comment: WHat do you mean by "if i type different name"?

Comment: i entered a different username in the EditText and it didn't return the username i entered. but it did return when i entered asdasd in the EditText. @AlexMamo sorry if its difficult for u to understand my english.

Comment: How do you check that? Please edit your question and show us the code.

Comment: i already edited my question because i change a bit of my code. i hope u understand what i mean. @AlexMamo

Comment: If you try to hardcode the `username` into `asdasd`, does it work?

Comment: it shows this in my logcat. 2021-08-09 19:38:34.552 8723-8723/com.example.efutric D/myapp: asdasd  @AlexMamo

Comment: In that case, the problem is what you are trying, right?

Comment: yes. im trying to store data into the database if the username is not exist in the database. @AlexMamo

Comment: So you actually just want to know if the `asdasd` exists and if it exists read the data? That's it?

Comment: yes that too. and i want if the asdasd doesnt exists, it will store asdasd into the database. unfortunately its not working. @AlexMamo

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you actually want to do. So if it exists, read the data, otherwise what would like to happen? Please provide an example.